# C# SerialPort receiving incorrect data compared to other tools

Tags: c#, serial-port

We have a system running Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB (with the latest Windows Updates) connected to a device that transmits binary data over RS232 in ESPA 4.4.4 format. We're using a Moxa [NPort 5100](https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/serial-device-servers/general-device-servers/nport-5100-series) ethernet to serial adapter to communicate with the device using a Virtual COM Port (created using the NPort Administrator tool).

We've implemented multiple similar systems in the past, but in this system alone, the C# `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class seems to be behaving in a very odd way.

The data we expect to receive looks like the following (Hex):

```
04 04 04 31 05 32 05 04 04 04 04 31 05 32 05
```

We used RealTerm on the system to capture what we were receiving, and it was correct. The serial settings in use are:

- **Baud Rate**: 9600bps
- **Parity**: None
- **Data Bits**: 8
- **Stop Bits**: 1
- **Flow Control**: None

When we use the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class (.net core 3.1, with the [`System.IO.Ports`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/) NuGet package at version `5.7.0`) however, we receive data that looks like the following (Hex):

```
Opened serial port: COM8 - Baud rate: 9600; Data bits: 8; Stop bits: One; parity: None
Received 3 bytes: 04 54 F8
Received 4 bytes: 44 A8 32 FF
Received 1 bytes: 44
Received 3 bytes: 82 05 AA
Received 1 bytes: E4
```

The test code we threw together looks as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

namespace TestSerial
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM8", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Opened serial port: {sp.PortName} - Baud rate: {sp.BaudRate}; Data bits: {sp.DataBits}; Stop bits: {sp.StopBits}; parity: {sp.Parity}");

            using IMemoryOwner<byte> buff = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024); 

            while (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                int numRead = sp.BaseStream.Read(buff.Memory.Span);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Received {numRead} bytes: {ConvertToHex(buff.Memory.Slice(0, numRead).Span)}");
            }
        }

        private static string ConvertToHex(in Span<byte> span)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string sep = "";

            foreach (byte b in span)
            {
                sb.Append(sep);
                sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

                sep = " ";
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I then implemented basically the same test program in C++ (and Go) as a sanity check, and it yields the correct results:

```
Opened serial port COM8 successfully, receiving
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 6 bytes: 4, 4, 31, 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 7 bytes: 4, 4, 4, 31, 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 6 bytes: 4, 4, 31, 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

std::string get_last_error_as_string()
{
    const auto error_message_id = GetLastError();

    if (error_message_id == 0)
    {
        return std::string();
    }

    LPSTR message_buffer = nullptr;
    const size_t size = FormatMessageA(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        nullptr, 
        error_message_id, 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&message_buffer), 
        0,
        nullptr
    );

    std::string message(message_buffer, size);

    if (message_buffer != nullptr)
    {
        LocalFree(message_buffer);
    }

    return message;
}

int main()
{
    const auto port = L"\\\\.\\COM8";

    const auto serial_handle = CreateFile(
        port, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0, 
        nullptr, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        nullptr
    );

    if (serial_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        const auto error_message = get_last_error_as_string();

        std::cerr << "Error opening serial port COM8: " << error_message;

        return -1;
    }


    DCB serial_parameters;
    serial_parameters.DCBlength = sizeof(serial_parameters);

    if (!GetCommState(serial_handle, &serial_parameters))
    {
        const auto error_message = get_last_error_as_string();

        std::cerr << "Error getting serial port state: " << error_message << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }

    serial_parameters.BaudRate = 9600;
    serial_parameters.ByteSize = 8;
    serial_parameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    serial_parameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
    serial_parameters.fParity = 0;
    serial_parameters.fBinary = 1;

    if (!SetCommState(serial_handle, &serial_parameters))
    {
        const auto error_message = get_last_error_as_string();

        std::cerr << "Error setting serial parameters: " << error_message << std::endl;

        CloseHandle(serial_handle);

        return -1;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeout;
    timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = MAXDWORD;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(serial_handle, &timeout))
    {
        const auto error_message = get_last_error_as_string();

        std::cerr << "Error setting serial timeouts: " << error_message << std::endl;

        CloseHandle(serial_handle);

        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Opened serial port COM8 successfully, receiving" << std::endl;

    char buff[1024];

    while (true)
    {
        DWORD num_read;

        if (!ReadFile(serial_handle, buff, 1024, &num_read, nullptr))
        {
            const auto error_message = get_last_error_as_string();

            std::cerr << "Failed to read from port: " << error_message << std::endl;

            CloseHandle(serial_handle);

            return -1;
        }

        if (num_read == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Received " << num_read << " bytes: ";
        std::string sep;

        for (auto i = 0; i < num_read; i++)
        {
            std::cout << sep;
            std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(buff[i]);

            sep = ", ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(serial_handle);
}
```

**Here's where it gets interesting**

If I do the following:

- Run the .net code
- Run the C++ code

The C++ code will output the wrong data, the same as the .net code.

However, if I do the following:

- Run the .net code
- Run RealTerm
- Run the C++ code

The C++ code will output the correct data.

It seems as though the .net `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class is setting a property on the COM port that causes the data to be received incorrectly. RealTerm appears to reset whatever property this is, but the C++ code on its own does not. The problem is, I cannot figure out what the property actually is!

As I said, we've implemented this befre multiple times without issue, but in this case things are not going as planned.

It's worth noting that the Moxa NPort can also act in a TCP server mode where you can simply connect via TCP and receive data. I've tested it in this mode and connected via telnet and the data rceived is correct.

### Some further testing

As suggested by @MickyD I've done some further testing under different scenarios (after reboots). THe results are as follows:

1. **Reboot, test c++**

Correct data:

```
Opened serial port COM8 successfully, receiving
Received 4 bytes: 4, 4, 4, 31
Received 3 bytes: 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 3 bytes: 4, 4, 4
Received 4 bytes: 31, 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 4 bytes: 4, 4, 4, 31
Received 3 bytes: 5, 32, 5
```

2. **Reboot, run RealTerm, test c++**

Correct data:

```
Opened serial port COM8 successfully, receiving
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 1 bytes: 4
Received 6 bytes: 4, 4, 31, 5, 32, 5
Received 1 bytes: 4
```

3. **Reboot, run c#**

Incorrect data:

```
Opened serial port: COM8 - Baud rate: 9600; Data bits: 8; Stop bits: One; parity: None
Received 4 bytes: 04 04 B1 32
Received 1 bytes: 84
Received 3 bytes: 04 05 05
Received 1 bytes: F4
Received 4 bytes: 06 00 92 FF
Received 3 bytes: 24 A1 41
```

4. **Reboot, run c#, run c++**

C# incorrect data:

```
Opened serial port: COM8 - Baud rate: 9600; Data bits: 8; Stop bits: One; parity: None
Received 4 bytes: 44 44 A8 F0
Received 1 bytes: 84
Received 1 bytes: 04
Received 3 bytes: 54 A8 F0
```

C++ incorrect data:

```
Opened serial port COM8 successfully, receiving
Received 4 bytes: 4, 54, ffffffa8, fffffff0
Received 1 bytes: fffffff4
Received 4 bytes: 44, 42, ffffff80, 5
Received 1 bytes: fffffffc
Received 4 bytes: ffffff84, 4, 5, ffffffff
```

Comment: I think its too early to point fingers just yet.  What I would do is restart your OS after each test to determine the likely culprit/combination. i.e. 1) reboot 2) test c++ code 3) reboot 4) run RealTerm 5) test c++ 6) reboot 7) test C# 8) reboot 9) test C# **then** 10) test c++ **without** rebooting.  Otherwise looking at your results above I could equally conclude that your C++ code requires RealTerm to be run first.  Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  At the moment you have two many variables a) language b) library c) defaults d) strange program order requirement

Comment: Hi @MickyD Sure, I'll give that a go. We have tested rebooting after applying Windows Updates and installing .net core 3.1 (it was previously .net core 3.0 and we upgraded via chocolatey, which we use to manage packages).

Comment: @MickyD question updated with the results of these tests, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's hard to say what the Virtual COM software is doing behind the scenes to emulate it as a serial port.  Windows 10 seems to make everything more complicated with elevation privileges. I would make sure you are running everything as administrator, including the virtual com software.  You'll have to right click it, go to properties, and compatibility and run as admin.  I've seen funky things like this with Win10 because things were being ran as administrator (even tho the windows login was a administrator).

Comment: Thanks for the update.  What happens if you run with hardware flow-control in C#?  i.e. DTR-DSR + RTS+CTS.   You might want to try 1 parity too